# Mqtt is not able to establish connection "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am getting below exception while establishing connection with mqtt broker

**Exception:**

java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade.

Code:

```
private MqttClient instantiateNewMqttConnection()  {
    logger.info("Intantiate new MQTT connection....");
    logger.info("Connecting to MQTT Broker: " + this.params.url);
    MqttClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new MqttClient(this.params.url, this.params.clientId, new MemoryPersistence());

        client.setCallback(new MqttConnectionCallBack(this.params.clientId));
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        options.setConnectionTimeout(0);
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(15000);
        //options.setSkipPortDuringHandshake(true);
        IMqttToken token = client.connectWithResult(options);
        token.waitForCompletion();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        logger.info("MQTT Connection Failed");
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        logger.info(e.getCause().toString());
        logger.info(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        Assert.fail("Failed due to MQTT connection could not be made");
    }
    return client;
}
```

Expectations : The connection should get established.

Comment: What does the Broker log say, if anything? What Broker software are you using?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delayed response, We are using AMAZON IOT CORE as a broker.. I don't have access to logs. Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: AWS IOT Core uses MQTT v3.1.1.  If your Java library only supports v5.x, you would get that error when trying to connect.

Comment: No eclipse paho supports 3.1.1, do you have any alternative solution which supports AWS IOT Core

Comment: how do you authenticate with the broker? Do you use the correct certificates and key?

Answer (score 0):

Try with 1.2.0 version. I faced same issue before, downgraded worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem:

there is a bug open with all version 1.2.* onwards that does not connect over wss for amazon iot core broker. to resolve this error they have provided a local fix. Go to the paho library github clone the repo and use the command to build the jar out of the repo.

use that jar as a dependency.
Thanks

Comment: If this is the solution to your question feel free to mark your answer as a solution as well. This helps the community, which proactively looks at unresolved questions.